# Android NDK, старт изучения

Tags: android, android-ndk

Встал перед вопросом, как лучше изучать android ndk, стоит ли идти по стопам изучения учебника, или есть ил какие-нибудь хорошие ресурсы для изучения(понятно, что это будет субъективно). Буду рад любой помощи